# header() function removes HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

There might be many releated question on SO and many articles about it, but I am unable to understand the reason for it.

What I am trying to achieve is we have some affiliate sort of thing. In that if a user clicks on any of our ads in google or anywhere else. He is taken to a page from where we redirect him to the approprite page. For redirecting we use the following code.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");  
header("Location: http://www.example.com/page2.php");
```

Suppose this code is written on `page1.php` and the user is redirected to `page2.php`. On the `page1` I get the referer from where the user is arrived (google.com for instance). But on `page2.php` we don't get referer as `page1`. Which seems to me as a strange behavior. Can anyone put light on the reason of this behavior.

PS: I have workaround this by adding a cookie just before redirect and retriving the value on `page2`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the referrer is sent by the browser (if allowed, not all browsers do it, and it can easily be changed by the client), meaning your page1 is never set as a referrer for page 2 as it's the server doing the redirection, not the client.
To my knowledge, There is no way to "fake" it, although the technique proposed by bansi looks tempting, I've seen multiple posts on the web indicating it actually doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

**IMPORTANT :** as noted by @cryptic and @Bartdude The following solution is tempting but won't work. Why this won't work is explained below.

--- Original solution  ---
Add `Referer` header also

```
header("Referer: http://www.the_referer_page");
```

The `Referer` is sent by the browser to the server. Because you are redirecting to another site you have to manually send the header to the other site as there is no browser involved.

--- Original solution end  ---

### Why the above solution wont work

The `HTTP referer` is sent by the browser to the server. When the `301 Moved Permanently` header is sent to the browser the server is telling the browser that this page is moved and load the page from the new location. It is then the browser's decision to request or don't request the page from the new location and what all the headers to be sent to the new server. Actually sending a `HTTP referer` header to the browser is really meaningless.

Sorry for the wrong solution provided. Hope this avoids someones temptation to use the `Referer` header as it tempted me.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question as to WHY it is happening. Also it is the BROWSER sending the referrer to the SERVER, not the other way around. You will be sending a referrer to the browser which does nothing.

Comment: @crypticツ was typing the answer..

Comment: Sending a *response referer header* from the server to the client still does exactly nothing.

Comment: @deceze you can redirect the `Referer` header to the other site. I think this is much more clean way than using cookies for this.

Comment: Only one problem: it doesn't work.